# How to make Add-Migration including private property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Right now I have models look like this:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    private byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Derived : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When running `Add-Migration` everything works as I expected but except for no `RowVersion` column creation.

Is there anyway to make it including `RowVersion` column?

Comment: I think you can use the [Column] Attribute over the private property.

Comment: I already tried that and it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Usualy EF allows you to map via fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity()
        .Property(p => p.Property);
}
```

**But your private Property is not visible....**

So you have to create a EntityTypeConfiguration, and register them:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    private byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public class BaseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Base>
    {
        public BaseConfiguration()
        {
            Property(p => p.RowVersion);
        }
    }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Configurations.Add(new Base.BaseConfiguration());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for idea! I already solved the problem by changing from private to protected instead. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the timestamp annotation:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Derived : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

why your drvied class is sealed?! Dynamic Proxy will not working! take care about that. and it must be public(For reflection).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But my problem is not incorrect column type.